# Error con startswith Python

Tags: python

Estoy ejecutando un servidor escrito en python, y me aparece este error al correrlo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "desarrollo/open/server/bin/openerp-server.py", line 124, in <module>
    pooljobs=False)
  File "/home/daniel/desarrollo/open/server/bin/pooler.py", line 47, in get_db_and_pool
    pool.get('ir.actions.report.xml').register_all(cr)
  File "/home/daniel/desarrollo/open/server/bin/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 100, in register_all
    opj('addons',r['report_xml']),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 75, in join
        if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Tengo python instalado en 2 equipos, con la misma versión y en uno funciona perfecto, pero en el otro equipo no.

Sé que la función startswith trabaja con strings, pero no sé porqué me dice NoneType cuando el en otro equipo se ejecuta correctamente.

El error está explotando con python propiamente:

`/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py` no en los archivos o módulos del servidor, por lo tanto el archivo posixpath no puedo modificarlo. Supongo porque es el código interno de alguna función de python

Como ya ven, estoy usando Ubuntu, 14.04, y la version del python en 2.7.6
Esto es igual para los dos equipos.

Este es el código de register_all:

```
def register_all(self, cr):
    """Report registration handler that may be overridden by subclasses to
       add their own kinds of report services.
       Loads all reports with no manual loaders (auto==True) and
       registers the appropriate services to implement them.
    """
    opj = os.path.join
    cr.execute("SELECT * FROM ir_act_report_xml WHERE auto=%s ORDER BY id", (True,))
    result = cr.dictfetchall()
    svcs = netsvc.Service._services
    for r in result:
        print r['report_xml'] # NO puedo poner el print aquí porque me da error de identación... 
        if svcs.has_key('report.'+r['report_name']): #...con esta línea, pero no entiendo, pues está bien identado 
            continue
        if r['report_rml'] or r['report_rml_content_data']:
            report_sxw('report.'+r['report_name'], r['model'],
                    opj('addons',r['report_rml'] or '/'), header=r['header'])
        if r['report_xsl']:
            report_rml('report.'+r['report_name'], r['model'],
                    opj('addons',r['report_xml']),
                    r['report_xsl'] and opj('addons',r['report_xsl']))
        print r['report_xml'] # Aqui el print de depuracion no me da error
```

Depurando con prints esta funcion en ambos equipos, el valor r['report_xml'] a veces es none o puede ser una ruta a un archivo xml. Supongo que cuando no hay xml el valor es none. El tema es que con algún valor None de la maquina en que da error, intenta entrar en el atributo startswith.

EL error que me da en el primer print es:

```
ir_actions.py:94:57: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
           if svcs.has_key('report.'+r['report_name']): # Y no comprendo...
```

Quisiera que me ayuden a ver que hay, o que no hay en esta pc que no funciona...

Saludos

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No puedo porque el archivo posixpath es propio de python, y no me deja modificarlo, ya lo intenté.

Comment: Tienen el mismo operativo las dos máquinas? (la que te funciona y la que no)

Comment: @abulafia, cierto!

Comment: SI, las dos son ubuntu 14.04

Comment: En la línea que tienes `if r['report_xsl']` yo pondría `if r['report_xls'] and r['report_xml']`, para asegurarme de que si `r['report_xml']` es `None` no entre por ahi y evitar la excepción. En cuanto a la indentación del `print()` seguro que se debe a que no hay el mismo número de espacios en todas las líneas, debido a que algunas usan <Tab>. Si puedes, edítalo con un editor que te haga visibles los caracteres invisibles para verificar esto. En una mala siempre puedes copiar la línea siguiente a la que te da error, pegarla, y editar el comando (para asegurar que tiene la misma indentación)

Comment: O usar el truco que usas pocas líneas antes e invocar `opj('addons', r['report_xml'] or '/')`, si es lo apropiado en este caso (si el report_xml no existe, es decir es None, usar una barra en su lugar)

Comment: @abulafia, como bien describiste en la respuesta, `r['report_xml']`   era None, puesto que faltaba configurar un addons path para que el servidor accediera a la carpeta con la lista de los módulos. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La línea en que te está saltando el error es la 75 de `/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py`. Eso es parte de la función `posixpath.join()`, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
def join(a, *p):
    """Join two or more pathname components, inserting '/' as needed.
    If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components
    will be discarded.  An empty last part will result in a path that
    ends with a separator."""
    path = a
    for b in p:
        if b.startswith('/'):
            path = b
        elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
            path +=  b
        else:
            path += '/' + b
    return path
```

El error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'` indica que en ese momento la variable `b` vale `None`. Por tanto, que se le ha pasado como parámetro a la función `join()` algún `None`.

Ya que según el *stacktrace* que has mostrado esto ocurre cuando se ejecuta esta otra línea (de tu fichero `/home/daniel/desarrollo/open/server/bin/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py`)

```
opj('addons',r['report_xml']),
```

sospecho que lo que está pasando es que `r['report_xml']` es `None`.

Comment: Sera que falta alguna libreria xml para python?

Comment: No creo que esa sea la causa. Mira a ver tu funcion `register_all()`, en `ir_actions.py`, y depura (por ejemplo intercalando `print()` para mostrar variables) qué tienes en `r` y por qué es diferente en cada máquina. Está relacionado,con el contenido del recurso `ir.actions.report.xml`

Comment: Chevere, déjame revisar y les informo que fué... gracias

Comment: Ok. Ejecuté las pruebas según @abulafia, depurando con prints en ambos equipos. En el que funciona,  el valor `r['report_xml']`  a veces es none o puede ser una ruta a un archivo xml. Supongo que cuando no hay xml el valor es none. En el equipo que da error, tambien el valor de `r['report_xml']`  es none o puede ser también una ruta con un xml. El tema es que con algún valor None de la maquina en que da error, intenta entrar  en el atributo startswith. Puedo voy a copiar los resultados en la pregunta por si no me di a entender bien aquí.